# Scope for declaration in java

Tags: java, scope, initialization, output, declaration

```
public class PerfectNumber {
        public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int num)
        {
            int sum;//sum initialization
            for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
            {
                if(num%i==0)
                    sum+=i;//Here it is showing the error that sum might not have been initialized
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Before you use a variable you must first init it,and you method need return a boolean result

Answer (score 0):

`int sum;//sum initialization`

wrong, this is just a declaration

try

`int sum = 0;//sum initialization`